# Using an array of structures with call by reference

Tags: c, structure, pass-by-reference

Here is my problem: I have to make this program for school and I spent the last hour debugging and googling and haven't found an answer.

I have an array of structures in my `main` and I want to give that array to my function `seteverythingup` (by call by reference) because in this function a string I read from a file is split up, and I want to write it into the structure but I always get a `SIGSEV` error when strcpy with the struct array.

**This is my main:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE* datei;
int size = 10;
int used = 0;
char line[1000];
struct raeume *arr = (raeume *) malloc(size * sizeof(raeume*));
if(arr == NULL){
    return 0;
}
if(argc < 2){
    return 0;
}
datei = fopen(argv[1], "rt");
if(datei == NULL){
    return 0;
}
fgets(line,sizeof(line),datei);
while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),datei)){
        int l = strlen(line);
        if(line[l-1] == '\n'){
            line[l-1] = '\0';
        }
           seteverythingup(&line,arr,size,&used);

}
ausgabeunsortiert(arr,size);
fclose(datei);
return 0;
}
```

**and this is my function:**

```
void seteverythingup(char line[],struct raeume *arr[], int size,int used)
{
    char *token,raumnummer[5],klasse[6];
    int tische = 0;
    const char c[2] = ";";
    int i=0;
    token = strtok(line, c);
    strcpy(raumnummer,token);
    while(token != NULL )
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, c);
        if(i==0){
            strcpy(klasse,token);
        }else if(i==1){
            sscanf(token,"%d",&tische);
        }
        i++;
    }
    managesize(&arr[size],&size,used);
    strcpy(arr[used]->number,raumnummer);
    strcpy(arr[used]->klasse,klasse);
    arr[used]->tische = tische;
    used++;
}
```

Comment: Technically C doesn't have call by reference, only call by value. You can *emulate* call by reference by using pointers to variables.

Comment: As for your problem, if your code does not cause the compiler to give you errors or warnings, you need to enable more warnings.

Comment: You allocated an array of pointers, but no space for what the pointers point to.

Comment: This line looks kind of suspect: `struct raeume *arr = (raeume *) malloc(size * sizeof(raeume*));` Where and how is `raeume` defined?

Comment: @stark ok so how do I fix this?

Comment: @user3078414 in my header file:                                                   typedef struct raeume{
char number[5];
char klasse[6];
int tische;
}raeume;

Comment: I can't understand your program if I don't see what is your important variable… You initialize a pointer to your struct or to some pointer?

Comment: @user3078414 I want to create an array of structs

Comment: Then don't add the indirection of the pointer.  Change the malloc to `size * sizeof(struct raeume)` and remove most of the `*`.  Change semantics to `strcpy(arr[used].number, raumnummer)`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Since there is more confusion I wrote a short program that works out the part you are having trouble with.

```
#include <cstdlib>

struct raeume {
    int foo;
    int bar;
};

void seteverythingup(struct raeume *arr, size_t len) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        arr[i].foo = 42;
        arr[i].bar = 53;
    }
}

int main() {
    const size_t size = 10;
    struct raeume *arr = (struct raeume*) malloc(size * sizeof(struct raeume));

    seteverythingup(arr, size);

    return 0;
}
```

So basically the signature of your functions is somewhat odd. Malloc returns you a pointer to a memory location. So you really dont need a pointer to an array. Just pass the function the pointer you got from malloc and the function will be able to manipulate that region.

Original Answer:

```
malloc(size * sizeof(raeume*));
```

This is probably the part of the code that gives you a hard time. `sizeof` returns the size of a type. You ask sizeof how many bytes a pointer to you raeume struct requires. what you probably wanted to do is ask for the size of the struct itself and allocate size times space for that. So the correct call to malloc would be:

```
malloc(size * sizeof(struct raeume));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you just solved a problem I didnt even know I had very well done, but I still cant figure why it just screws up when I give it to my function. In my main it works totally fine but in my function it just says: 0xbaadf00d when I look at the memory for the array

Comment: Okay great. I have expanded on my answer since you were asking for more help. Please consider marking the answer as answered.